# Intercepting Arithmetic Operations in C program

Tags: c, gcc, intercept, integer-arithmetic

Is there a way that we can call user defined function when we are calling arithmetic operator in a C program just like operator overloading in C++. using GNU GCC Compiler?
Simply,
I have a function add(), and in my C program I have arithmetic Operation

```
 c = a + b;
```

when I compile the program, it should call my add() function internally for + operator.

and Is there a way we can see what is the code that gcc compiler is calling when it encounters + operator?

Comment: You can use the gcc `-S` option to compile from C to assembly language, so you can examine the code it generates.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful :-).

Answer (score 1):

No.

C does not work that way, you cannot overload/override the basic built-in operators.

Seeing the code is of course possible, either by making gcc emit it directly [using `-S`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S), or by disassembling the resulting binary. The related binutils tool is [`objdump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump).

These days much such exploration can also be made "online" using the fantastic Compiler Explorer tools at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org), of course.

Comment: Thank you for the link :-). recently i was working with arm-buildroot-linux-uclibceabi-gcc compiler where i was able to redirect the calls of floating point operations +,-,*. Since the compiler was cross compiler similarly, wouldn't that be possible in gcc itself ?